# Subdomain to point to subdirectory of main site?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, subdomain

I have my website running at:

> www.example.com

I also have this other domain:

> www.example.net

Is it possible to point "www.example.net" to a subdirectory of "www.example.com"? For example:

> www.example.net-> www.example.com/other

?

It's not just a redirect, I need to serve the pages and see "www.example.net" in the user's browser.

What do you think?

We use IIS7 and everything is ASP.NET (aspx pages, ascx controls, etc).

Comment: be careful posting random example domains: are you sure you know where they point to?  Use 'example' for example domains and see rfc 2606

Comment: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]

RewriteCond  Host:  (?:www\.)?other\.com
RewriteRule  (.*)   http://www.domain.com/other$1 [I,L]
```

Comment: vartec, can the same be accomplished with IIS7 only, or a free alternative?

Comment: Well, actually you're in luck. IIS7 does indeed provide similar functionality. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at two methods for this:

- URL rewriter
- Server.Execute method

The first is a httpmodule that silently redirects the request without changing the url in the address bar, the second is a method you can call within aspx code. I think the latter is only good though if you're working in the same application, so I would go with the URL rewriter.

There is an official iis7 URL rewriter available on www.iis.net afaik.

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks, but can URL rewrite work across different applications in IIS7? How should I set up this in IIS? I create a new application for www.other.com , and set the URL rewrite there?

Answer (score 0):

Two questions for you:

1. Can you set them up as two different web sites in IIS?
2. If someone visited example.net/page.htm, would that be the same as example.com/other/page.htm?

If the answer is yes to both of those, why not just setup a new web site in IIS and point it to the "other" file path.

Comment: Both answers are yes. Would it inherit web.config and other configuration from the "main"/root site? Or I'd need to keep other config files inside /other for this?

Comment: good point...it would not inherit the config files.  There would need to be some in the "other" directory.

Comment: Thanks. There's another limitation to this, as our controls are stored in main website /controls folder. If I point the "other" domain to /other, and reference controls at /controls, it won't find it - I've just tested and it says something like "Parser Error, file could not be found".